# Is it possible to use the index inside of a CSS rule?

Tags: css

Suppose I want a list that fades from the bottom. I might hand-code this as:

```
/* etc... */

ul > li:nth-last-child(4) {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

ul > li:nth-last-child(3) {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

ul > li:nth-last-child(2) {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

ul > li:nth-last-child(1) {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Can I instead access the index in the rule?

For example:

```
ul > li:nth-last-child(n) {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, n / 10);
}
```

Comment: don't think you can do that in css, you would need a preprocessor like sass

Comment: or even javascript

Comment: You could create a similar effect by overlaying a gradient on the `ul`

Comment: @ovokuro Not quite; I want the background to show through.

Comment: @sdgfsdh You can have multiple backgrounds on one element. So `background-image: linear-gradient(whatever), url('your picture here');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use something like this :

```css
ul {
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #fff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>aaa</li>
</ul>
```

By the way this is not supported in all browser, you can read more about [text-fill-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color) and [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

Answer (score 2):

Not in that way, no. But you can mask the entire list with a fading gradient:

```css
ul {
  font: 11pt/1.4em sans-serif;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  <li>sit amet, consectetur</li>
  <li>adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Praesent mollis, nisl eget tincidunt consequat,</li>
  <li>sem risus semper lectus,</li>
  <li>ut iaculis massa est at tortor.</li>
  <li>Mauris dolor turpis,</li>
  <li>vulputate id arcu elementum
</ul>
```

This will work over any background. It's not supported in IE and Edge though: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

The `background-clip` property might be a better option if you need to support old browsers (it behaves a bit different than mask-image though, try it over an image background for example). See @TemaniAfif's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222950/3776299

Edge also supports SVG masks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask

Comment: Cool +1 I hadn't heard of that property. Pity it has limited support!

Comment: @TemaniAfif i upvoted your answer and added a link to it, `background-clip` seems to have a bit better browser support than `mask-image` :)

Comment: i upvoted yours too, as i didn't know about `mask-image`, learned new thing ;)